# Update the element name based on xpath from external file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest how to update the elements' name based on external file based on xpath given in it.

I have tried, with few variables to store the xpath from external file, template matched element's xpath, but unable to get the required info. Please suggest.

**External file (FindReplaceElements.ini):**

```
<root>
<tofind>aside/p</tofind>    <toreplace><p class="aside_Para"></p></toreplace>
<tofind>aside[@class="sidenote1"]/p</tofind>    <toreplace><p class="aside_Para1"></p></toreplace>
<tofind>body/p</tofind>    <toreplace><p class="body_Para"></p></toreplace>
<tofind>body/div/div/h1</tofind>    <toreplace><p class="body_h_2"></p></toreplace>
<tofind>body/div/div/div/h1</tofind>    <toreplace><p class="body_h_3"></p></toreplace>
</root>
```

**Input XML:**

```
<article>
<body>
    <p>The body para1</p>
    <aside><p>Aside para1</p></aside>
    <aside class="sidenote1"><p>Aside para2</p></aside>
    <div><div class="special"><h1>The Heading1</h1></div></div>
    <div><div><div><h1>The Heading2</h1></div></div></div>
</body>
</article>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<article>
<body>
    <p class="body_Para">The body para1</p>
    <aside><p class="aside_Para">Aside para1</p></aside>
    <aside class="sidenote1"><p class="aside_Para1">Aside para2</p></aside>
    <div><div class="special"><p class="body_h_2">The Heading1</p></div></div>
    <div><div><div><p class="body_h_3">The Heading2</p></div></div></div>
</body>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="varDocElemsIni" select="document('FindReplaceElements.ini')"/>
<xsl:variable name="varDQote">"</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="nodeAsStr"><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></xsl:variable><!--String name of element -->
    <xsl:variable name="varAllMatchedEles">            <!--getting Elements name from INI file-->
        <xsl:for-each select="$varDocElemsIni/root/tofind">
            <xsl:variable name="varNextElemINI"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/name()"/></xsl:variable><!--From INI file, required element name-->
            <xsl:variable name="varPathINI"><!--xPath of element from INI file-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$varDocElemsIni/root/tofind/tokenize(text(), '/')[not(position()=last())]">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:value-of select="'/'"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="varNameElem1">
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(text(), '/')[last()]">
                    <xsl:if test=". = $nodeAsStr">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$varNextElemINI"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="varPath"><!--xPath of Element from given input file -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::*[2]/name(), '/', parent::*/name())"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$varAllMatchedEles=$varPath">
            <xsl:element name="{$varNextElemINI}"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**One more XSLT tried as below:** but unable to get result

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="varDocElemsIni" select="document('FindReplaceElements.ini')"/>
<xsl:variable name="vardQote">"</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:call-template name="TempInsertElemsAttribs"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h2">
    <xsl:call-template name="TempInsertElemsAttribs"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="TempInsertElemsAttribs">
    <xsl:variable name="varReqElemName">
        <xsl:for-each select="$varDocElemsIni/root/tofind/*[name()=current()/name()]">
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::tofind/following-sibling::*[1][name()='toreplace']/child::*/name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="varReqElemNameAttrib">
        <xsl:for-each select="$varDocElemsIni/root/tofind/*[name()=current()/name()]/parent::tofind/following-sibling::*[1][name()='toreplace']/child::*/@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '=', $vardQote, ., $vardQote)"/><xsl:if test="not(position()=last())"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($varReqElemName) gt 0">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$varReqElemName"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length($varReqElemNameAttrib) gt 0"><xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $varReqElemNameAttrib)"/></xsl:if>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$varReqElemName"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Dynamic XPath evaluation is a standard feature of XSLT 3.0. If you can use XSLT 3.0, then use the `<xsl:evaluate>` instruction: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath

Comment: Thanks for suggestion sir, but i haven't using xslt3.0.

Comment: Rudramuni_TP: A somewhat limited XPath evaluation capability (such as only path expressions without any predicates) can be implemented in XSLT, however the provided FindReplaceElements.ini file already contains predicates. In the past I implemented a full XPath 2.0 parser completely in XSLT 2.0, but this only produces a parse tree -- and doesn't perform evaluation. So, either you limit the language, or you could use an extension function, such as exslt's `dyn:evaluate()` , as described here: http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html .

Comment: Then, you have to find an XSLT processor that implements (very few do) `dyn:evaluate()`

Comment: As suggested i will try sir, again thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @RudramuniTP Do you have control over the format of the external document? If yes, write each rule as an XSLT template. Then include/ import these templates into your main stylesheet. If not, do a preliminary transformation and transform each rule into a template.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sir, no control on external file, we thought of centralizing XSLT, only user can update the requirement, if Xpath of external file meets. Here elements 'p', 'h1', 'h2' ... are having few 'DIV' as their parents, based on some count 'div's as their parent, required 'element with attribute may differ from project to project. In such cases user will alter the required elements name in external file.

Comment: @RudramuniTP I am afraid I don't follow. As I said, if you do not control the external file's format, start by transforming it to *templates*.

Comment: Your suggestion correct sir. I will try as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you do this in two steps:

First, apply the following stylesheet to the "external file":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <axsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
        <axsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <axsl:copy>
                <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </axsl:copy>
        </axsl:template>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tofind"/>
    </axsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tofind">
    <axsl:template match="{.}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::toreplace[1]/*"/>
    </axsl:template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="toreplace/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result in your example will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="aside/p">
      <p class="aside_Para">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="aside[@class=&#34;sidenote1&#34;]/p">
      <p class="aside_Para1">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="body/p">
      <p class="body_Para">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="body/div/div/h1">
      <p class="body_h_2">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="body/div/div/div/h1">
      <p class="body_h_3">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This result is an XSLT stylesheet of its own. Applying it your input example will produce the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><article>
<body>
    <p class="body_Para">The body para1</p>
    <aside><p class="aside_Para">Aside para1</p></aside>
    <aside class="sidenote1"><p class="aside_Para1">Aside para2</p></aside>
    <div><div class="special"><p class="body_h_2">The Heading1</p></div></div>
    <div><div><div><p class="body_h_3">The Heading2</p></div></div></div>
</body>
</article>
```

Note that some of these rules are ambiguous. There are dangers you undertake when you farm out the process of producing an XSLT to external agents.

Comment: Sir, superb suggestion, you shown me very important way of dealing the requirements. What a great solution. I assume no word 'impossible' from Michael sir. Plus one sir.